# How to release GPU resources in keras in ipython in spyder?

Tags: python, ipython, keras, spyder, tensorflow

When I typically run a python script from command line, for example, `python test.py`, the GPU memory will be released just after the script finished.
In this `test.py` script, I simply loaded a keras built model to evaluate and predict some data. No training process in it.
However, if I open my 'spyder', and run this script in 'spyder', the results come in the 'ipython' section, but then I type `nvidia-smi` from command line, the GPU memory is not released.
So, what I tried is close this 'ipython' kernel and start a new one. But all my other variables will be lost. Is there a decent way to release the GPU memory after `model.evaluate(x, y)` from 'spyder'?
Here are some screen shots:
[image]

Before and after running the script from 'spyder':
[image]

Comment: try running `gc.collect()`

Comment: @djk47463, where does this `gc` coming from? Whichi module?

Comment: the module is named [gc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html), it is a garbage collector, and I believe it comes with the python install

Comment: Did you find a way to release the GPU memory?

Comment: @user3731622, sorry, I didn't. And I have already not been using spyder for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, tensorflow backend will reserve all the memory on the GPU. It may not really use all of the memory, but it will be kept occupied from being used by other programs until tensorflow backend is terminated. So in `nvidia-smi` you will see the memory is not release even tensorflow has released the previous memory in its framework.

Comment: so how can I release the memory then? Because I run some test command from the ipython, and also run some other scripts from command line. But if the tensorflow backend doesn't release the memory, then I can't run other scripts from command line. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, you can limit the tensorflow memory. Please check [this link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1538)